# A question about Cauchy product

Tags: analysis

Consider the following two properties of a real divergent sequence $\{c_n\}$.

$(1) \;$ $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{c_n}{n}=M$ for some $M\in\mathbb{R}$.

$(2) \;$ There exist two real convergent  sequences $\{a_n\}$, $\{b_n\}$ such that $c_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_kb_{n-k}$.

Are $(1)$ and $(2)$ equivalent?

I know how to prove $(2) \implies (1)$, but I don't know whether $(1)$ implies $(2)$.

Comment: The title does not match what you ask

Comment: A test case.  $c_n = (-1)^n$.  Find $a_n, b_n$.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar coefficients of the power series $(1+x)^{1 /2}$ do converge to 0

Comment: So: assume $\lim c_n/n = 0$.  Let $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n$ which has radius of convergence (at least) $1$.  Then do the Taylor coefficients of $f(x)^{1/2}$ converge to zero?  Is there an example of this where $f(x)$ has no single-valued square-root on the unit disk?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar this power series may easily have 0 inside the unit didk which makes taking a square root quite problematic

Comment: The power series really don't seem that useful since it's hard to tell when the coefficients of $f$ converge (or maybe I'm missing something).

Comment: A reformulation is: Consider the bilinear map $F: c\times c \to c$ ($c$ = convergent sequences), $F(a,b)_n=(1/n)(a*b)_n$. Is $F$ surjective?

Comment: I suspect it was not a good idea migrating the question here.

Answer (score 7):

*This question was migrated from MathOverflow because it can be answered on Mathematics Stack Exchange.*

That is technically correct, of course, but that is true about *every* question (because both sites are frequented by pretty much the same people and the snobs that make it a matter of principle to post on MO but not on MSE are very few if they exist at all).

*The power series really don't seem that useful since it's hard to tell when the coefficients of $f$ converge (or maybe I'm missing something).*

Actually, the power series *is* useful to the extent that it solves the problem in no time combined with another famous principle, which is "*If you don't know how to build something, build it at random*".

So, let $f(z)=\sum_ka_kz^k$, $g(z)=\sum_k b_k z^k$, $h(z)=\sum_k c_kz^k$, $|z|<1$. If $a,b$ are bounded, then
$$
\|f(r\cdot)\|_{L^2(\mathbb T)}^2=\sum_k |a_k|^2r^{2k}=O(1/(1-r))
$$
as $r\to 1$ and similarly for $g$. So we must have
$$
\|h\|_{L^1(\mathbb T)}=O(1/(1-r))
$$
by Cauchy.

Now take a random sequence $c_k=\pm k^{p}$ with $p\in(\frac 12,1))$, say (so $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{c_n}n=0$). Then the expectation of the $L^1$-norm of the corresponding random $h(r\cdot)$ on the unit circumference is comparable to the expectation of its $L^2$-norm (or any other $L^p$ norm) by the usual probabilistic nonsense about sums of independent Rademacher random variables. But the $L^2$-norm is deterministic and its square equals $\sum_k k^{2p}r^{2k}\approx (1-r)^{-1-2p}$, which is too much. It formally remains to show that we can choose signs so that the corresponding equivalences hold for a whole sequence of $r$'s going to $1$, but that is easy if we notice that for every fixed $r$, only a finite number of the coefficients really matter in the norm computation and that for every fixed finite number of indices, the contribution of the corresponding $c_k$ is bounded and, therefore, negligible when comparing the norms to $(1-r)$ to a negative power for $r$ close to $1$.

This raises several interesting questions however, the simplest of which being what happens if we assume that $c_n=O(\sqrt n)$ rather than $c_n=O(n)$, so don't hurry to close the discussion :-).